# Integrate mapbox with Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, mapbox

Does anyone know if the framework Mapbox seamlessly works on Flutter (iOS and Android)?
The feature I want in my app is turn-by-turn navigation, for which Mapbox does have Android and iOS SDK. The package that is available for this in Flutter https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation does have the ability, as per the docs, but doesn't work as expected in Android (I tried only in Android).
There seems to be an open issue in their Github repository too - https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/issues/98
which pulls me back from using this.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

We already tried that plugin you will need to plugins to make complete working app. One is

https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl

this repo is working on Map view activities.

whereas this plugin is essential for navigation view activities
https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/issues/98

both have different functionalities.

Right now issue is merging both of them.

eopeter is not maintaining repo anymore you can use. it is updated

https://github.com/csongorkeller/flutter_mapbox_navigation

The merging issue is resolved here at

https://github.com/messenger2011/flutter-mapbox-gl

Comment: Does the repository by messenger2011 also include iOS support?

Answer (score -1):

Go through this blog : https://www.mapbox.com/blog/test-out-the-maps-plugin-for-flutter and try out the plugins they have provided

Below is the code to implement mapbox in your flutter app using [mapbox_gl](https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl) plugin :

```
MapboxOverlay(
  controller: MapboxOverlayController(),
  options: MapboxMapOptions(
    style: Style.dark,
    camera: new CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(lat: 52.376316, lng: 4.897801),
      zoom: 15.0,
      bearing: 0.0,
      tilt: 0.0),
    ),
  )
```

You can also try this one : https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_navigation

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: The question asked for navigation. The suggested package (the first one) is a link to a deprecated package that doesn't support navigation.